# PhantomJS / CasperJS injecting script with parameters

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I am familiar with the injectJs and includeJs calls, in relation to PhantomJS/CasperJS. But, how do I add external Javascript with the following form:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
```

Please note the two parameters "async" and "defer". Thanks.

Comment: Why do you care about `async` and `defer`? This shouldn't make any difference when injecting. Also, there is a good chance that the injection happens after the page loaded

Comment: It's required of Google's Javascripts that rely on these parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't figure out how to insert valueless attributes as I defined in my original question with PhantomJS / CasperJS. But it turns out, Google reCAPTCHA JS SDK works as intended if I do insert the value "true" to the two attributes. So, I injected the two attributes as:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async="true" defer="true"></script>
```

and it worked fine, even though their document only has the valueless attributes.